# Is there is a way to get Pull Request ID in Azure DevOps after clicking on complete button in Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm executing a pipeline flow after creating a PR and I need to get Pull Request ID after I click the complete button.

I'm using **$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)** to fetch the value, but it is always an empty value and gives the error output "**System.PullRequest.PullRequestId: command not found**"

Create a simple classical pipeline like below and it needs to be called in **Branch Policies -> Status Check**.
[image]

**Note:** With the same variable ***$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)*** I'm able to get the ID before the completion i.e., when PR is in an active state.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml): _"This variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy"_

Comment: Hi @Hello, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, No, it didn't serve the exact purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Ad **@CodeCaster** said in the comment, the variable `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy.

But, you can get the last completed PR ID with small PS script via the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1):

```
$header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"  }
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pullrequests/?searchCriteria.status=3&top=50&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/master&api-version=6.1"
$pullRequests = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType application/json
Write-Host "Last PR completed to master is: $($pullRequests.value[0].pullRequestId)"
```

Just replace the `master` in the `$url` with your target branch name.

Results:
[image]

*Don't forget to enable the access token if you use the Classic editor or add the token to your YAML task.*

Comment: As @codecaster said, I'm running the complete build in a single flow based on branch policies and not individually. Using API I can get the last completed PR but I cannot validate it is the PR that is executed previously.

Example:
Complete PR is created with a flow of two pipelines.
1st pipeline with PRid 1234 is run, accepted and completed.
After clicking complete the 2nd pipeline run based on branch policies, now with API I can get 1234 but I cannot check whether is it the same one completed previously.

Note: I'm not running individual CI it is a flow.

Comment: @Hello in the api response, the PR in location `0` in the last completed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could this is by extracting PR ID from merge commit message using regex expression.
Merge commit message is available using `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` environment variable in CI (Yes CI after merging the PR) build and then I used `Merged PR (\d*):.*` regex expression to extract the PR Id.

I see the merge commit message is generally generated as `Merged PR [PR ID]: [PR Title]`
e.g. `Merged PR 123456: My first PR in the world of coding :)`